# How to get BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER on api 21 Android

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

Why does getIntProperty return zero on the api device 21

```
val batteryManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
val BatteryCapacity = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER)
```

Comment: It is possible that the hardware does not support that particular property.

Comment: FWIW, it is mentioned in [the documentation of `getIntProperty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#getIntProperty(int)): "If the property is not supported or there is any other error, return (a) 0 if targetSdkVersion < VERSION_CODES.P or (b) Integer.MIN_VALUE if targetSdkVersion >= VERSION_CODES.P."